# css overwritten by script editor in parent page

Tags: web-part, css

I have subsite page(home.aspx) which for some reason inherits the css from a script editor in default.aspx(parent page). I'm basically changing the color of home.aspx css webpart header, I want it to be red in the home.aspx page. For some reason the parent's page Script editor style overrwrites it.

how do i prevent this from happening. (note that this is when you edit page and create a script editor with style. Below are the screenshots:

[image]

below is the script:
[image]

Comment: **note that if its still in edit mode, the red background color is okay, but if i exit out of the edit mode, it seems to get the bg color from the other page.

Comment: Those who know CSS will cause you bodily harm if they see you use ``!important`` Because when it is applied it can no longer be undone by any other CSS rule in the page. Instead learn to apply **CSS Specificity**   ; which **is applied** in OPs screenshot where you see ``.ms-Webpart-titleText`` used **2 times** (in the first Selector) So if you apply the class a 3th time, you increase Specificity. Documentation: See: https://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

Answer (score 0):

You can specify like `!important` for the css style to over right and apply.
See the below sample

```
 .ms-Webpart-titleText {
    background-color:Blue!important;
    font-size: 13px!impotant;
    }
```

Please check and apply for your css script.